# How to add and display multiple records

Tags: android

I'm working on a Shopping cart.

Right now I'm Scanning an item in Qr-code it is fetching one record and displaying in the first row.

Now when I scan another Qr-code I need to display in the second row, But it is replacing the first row.

please help me to come out this query.

Comment: share you code where you add new item

Comment: how to display new row, it like add to cart scenario

Comment: you need to more explain about your question @Lokesh

Comment: Please explain more thats the issue

Comment: the scenario:
User scans a barcode of the product, which is sent to server to find its details. the required details is fetched and displayed in the row.(I have done this).

Now again the user scans a barcode of other product, its details should be displayed in the second row.. similarly for 3rd and 4th products,.. etc

Please help me solve this scenario.